# Do firearms do different amount of damage to shield/armor/barrier like in Mass Effect 2?

Tags: mass-effect-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do certain weapons do more damage to shields/barriers/armour in Mass Effect 3?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53610/do-certain-weapons-do-more-damage-to-shields-barriers-armour-in-mass-effect-3)

I can't find a question that fits this description, so I assume this hasn't been asked before.

If you have a look at this ME Wikia page for the [Shuriken](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/M-4_Shuriken), it displays the same gun model for both ME2 and ME3. In the ME2 infobox, it shows the bonus damage it does to various types of defence, but in the ME3 infobox, it doesn't and neither does the description.

Does ME3 implement this sort of bonus damage or has it been removed? If it does, then how can I see them?

Comment: I have to note that I haven't yet played this game. So if this is obvious to people who have played the game, I do apologize.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have no idea why this didn't pop up in the suggestions.